# C++ container for list and map

Tags: c++, list, stl, dictionary

we have a collection of key and value pairs. We are in the need for a container which can help us to retrieve the value o(1) but also remember the insertion order so that when we do iteration, we could iterate like a inserting order. Since the key is a string, we will not able to use a set or similar structure.

Currently we have defined our own collection class which contains a list, also a map and the values are stored into 2 different structure.

Are there any readily available implementation available?

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you need a [Boost Multi-Index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) container.

Comment: In particular, the [bidirectional list with fast lookup example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#list_fast_lookup) appears to be relevant.

Comment: @Autopulated, anything other than boost?

Comment: @Gopalakrishnan : Sure, you could always use a crappy, hand-rolled implementation of what the Boost library in question already does, but why would you want to?

Comment: @Gopalakrishnan Subramani: copy-paste from Boost? Why do you need a "readily available implementation", but not Boost?

Comment: I wonder boost has 40+ MB of stuff to compile for a simple container? I have used boost for boost.python. Even pre-compiled output took a long time to compile boost related libraries..OR I miss something?

Comment: boost multi-index is header-only: nothing to compile at all!

Comment: @Gopalakrishnan : Boost is a collection of libraries; if you only need one or two, you can extract individual libraries from the Boost tree with the [bcp](http://www.boost.org/tools/bcp/index.html) utility.