# C++ Indexed Queue data structure required

Tags: c++, data-structures, boost

I have a `queue` of watches. The `watch` at the front is supposed to expire sooner than the rest. So watches are pushed to the back of the queue and pop'ed from the front of the queue. So far it looks like queue is the data structure applicable for this scenario.

However each watch has an identifier key of type `KeyT`. KeyT is `LessThanComparable`. There can be multiple watches identified by the same key. Often a notification associated with a key is emitted. Then the corresponding watches identified with the same key has to be notified and removed from the `queue (?)`. So it is desirable that the corresponding watches will be found in  sub-linear time.

So the requirements of the container is

1. push back
2. pop front
3. indexed
4. remove middle

Currently I am using `std::list` because I am performing deletion in the middle. To find the matching watches I need to perform a linear search through the entire list (missed 3). `std::queue` cannot be used because its not iterable.

Another solution that I've not yet implemented is to have two containers. As `std::list` is a stable container, the iterators won't be invalidated by deletion of some other element. So its safe to store the iterator inside `std::map`. On the other hand the requirement 3 is satisfied.

1. `std::list<watch>`
2. `std::multimap<KeyT, std::list<watch>::iterator>`

On the other hand it increases memory requirement. Also every insertion and deletion has to be performed twice on two containers. Is there any other bottleneck / loophole ? Is there any existing alternative to solve this problem ? Is there any container data structure in `boost` that serves the requirements of this problem ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ container for list and map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256468/c-container-for-list-and-map)

Comment: Also: [Searchable stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847049/searchable-stack)

Comment: @JaMiT I am aware of boost multi index but would that provide push pop performance like std::list ? Also the question you refered is focused on a completely different problem. Which is related to bimap also.

Comment: Completely different problem? *The first:* a collection of key and value pairs (`KeyT` and `watch`), remember insertion order (FIFO), and retrieve the value from a key (indexed). *The second:* stack-like structure (not FIFO, but some structures readily switch between LIFO and FIFO), and allows efficient searching of the contents (indexed). So 75% of your listed requirements are called out in those questions themselves (as opposed to being brought up in the answers), a far cry from "completely different".

Comment: For your performance concerns, see [the complexity documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/seq_indices.html#complexity_signature). Insertion and deletion from a sequenced index is O(1), like a linked list.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to use Boost Multi-Index:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3fd15865b3e35ab)**

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <chrono>

#include <random>
#include <boost/range/istream_range.hpp> // make_iterator_range
#include <thread> // sleep_for
#include <iostream>

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using boost::make_iterator_range;

using KeyT = int;

namespace { // generate demo data
    std::mt19937 s_prng{ std::random_device{}() };

    auto gen_expiration() {
        return Clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(std::uniform_int_distribution{1, 100}(s_prng));
    }
    auto gen_key() {
        return std::uniform_int_distribution{10, 20}(s_prng);
    }
}

struct Watch {
    size_t id;
    Watch(int id) : id(id) {}

    Clock::time_point expires_at = gen_expiration();
    KeyT key = gen_key();

    void notify() const {
        auto dt = (expires_at - Clock::now()) / 1.0ms;
        if (dt > 0) {
            std::cout
                << "Watch #" << id << " key " << key
                << " notified with " << dt << "ms to spare\n";
        } else {
            std::cout
                << "Watch #" << id << " key " << key
                << " expired " << -dt << "ms ago\n";
        }
    }
};

using Watches = bmi::multi_index_container<Watch,
    bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::sequenced<>,
        bmi::ordered_non_unique<
            bmi::tag<struct by_expiration>,
            bmi::member<Watch, Clock::time_point, &Watch::expires_at>
        >,
        bmi::ordered_non_unique<
            bmi::tag<struct by_key>,
            bmi::member<Watch, KeyT, &Watch::key>
        >
    > >;

int main() {
    Watches ww;

    for (auto id=0; id<100; ++id) 
        ww.emplace_back(id);

    // pop ends
    ww.front().notify();
    ww.pop_front();

    ww.back().notify();
    ww.pop_back();

    // erase middle
    {
        auto it = std::next(ww.begin(), ww.size()/2);
        it->notify();
        ww.erase(it);
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(50ms);
    std::cout << "\n--- notify the unlucky ones\n";
    auto& idx = ww.get<by_key>();
    for (auto [it,end] = idx.equal_range(13); it != end;) {
        it->notify();
        it = idx.erase(it);
    }

    ww.remove_if([](Watch const& w) { return w.key == 14; });
}
```

Which prints output like

```
Watch #0 key 10 notified with 42.7361ms to spare
Watch #99 key 11 notified with 12.8534ms to spare
Watch #50 key 12 notified with 30.7122ms to spare

--- notify the unlucky ones
Watch #7 key 13 expired 18.664ms ago
Watch #19 key 13 notified with 25.3537ms to spare
Watch #22 key 13 notified with 32.3545ms to spare
Watch #23 key 13 expired 29.6482ms ago
Watch #36 key 13 expired 23.6241ms ago
Watch #51 key 13 expired 17.5943ms ago
Watch #54 key 13 expired 41.5833ms ago
Watch #57 key 13 notified with 29.4185ms to spare
Watch #66 key 13 notified with 27.4347ms to spare
Watch #74 key 13 expired 25.5515ms ago
Watch #78 key 13 notified with 20.4526ms to spare
Watch #83 key 13 notified with 18.4592ms to spare
Watch #96 key 13 notified with 10.4945ms to spare
```

Note that I completely gratuitously threw in the index by expiration, which you may or may not need.

Comment: Added [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3fd15865b3e35ab) (with minor fix as well)

Comment: What is the complexity of erasing something in the middle ? in `std::list` is `O(1)` but here complexity of `erase` is `O(n)`. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/seq_indices.html

Comment: The complexity of erasing is the sum of complexities for each index, O(1) + O(1) (amortized) + O(1) (amortized) = O(1) (amortized).

Comment: Thank you @JoaquínMLópezMuñoz you beat me to it, and got a lot more accurate than I would have been too.